# Number of ways of distributing n identical balls into groups such that each group has atleast k balls?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming

I am trying to do this using recursion with memoization ,I have identified the following base cases .

I) when n==k there is only one group with all the balls.

II) when k>n then no groups can have atleast k balls,hence zero.

I am unable to move forward from here.How can this be done?

As an illustration when n=6 ,k=2
   (2,2,2)
    (4,2)
    (3,3)
    (6)

That is 4 different groupings can be formed.

Comment: Try to come up with a statement that *partitions* the possibilities, like "Every valid solution consists of a ___ followed by a ___".  It's easiest if the first ___ is a "simple" object. The idea is that we could count the total number of solutions by counting the number of solutions for each choice of the first ___, and then adding them all together.  This also means that it must not be possible to count any solution twice (i.e., under two different choices for the first ___).

Comment: E.g. if the problem was to count the number of ways to order a list of n items, we could say, "Every ordering of n items consists of one of the items, followed by an ordering of the remaining n-1 items."  This has the important property of avoiding double-counting: it partitions the orderings into n buckets according to their first item, and since any particular ordering has exactly one first item, it will be counted exactly once.  Counting orderings of n-1 items is then easy -- it can be done using the same function we just wrote to count orderings of n items! :)

Comment: In this particular problem it's less obvious how to partition the solutions, because the order of the groups doesn't matter -- that is, (4, 2) is "the same as" (2, 4), so it should only be counted once.  (You should be explicit about this in your question, BTW.)  Can you modify the problem somehow to get around this?  Hint: For most solutions, the list of groups can be written in many different orders; if there was an easy way to pick one specific ordering from this set, you could simply count the number of *such orderings* of solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be represented by the two dimensional recursive formula described below:

```
T(0, k) = 1
T(n, k) = 0   n < k, n != 0
T(n, k) = T(n-k, k)                 +           T(n, k + 1)
             ^                                       ^
    There is a box with k balls,        No box with k balls, advance to next k
            put them
```

In the above, `T(n,k)` is the number of distributions of `n` balls such that each box gets at least `k`.

And the trick is to think of `k` as the lowest possible number of balls, and seperate the problem to two scenarios: Is there a box with exactly `k` balls (if so, place them and recurse with `n-k` balls), or not (and then, recurse with minimal value of `k+1`, and same number of balls).

**Example**, to calculate your example: `T(6,2)` (6 balls, minimum 2 per box):

```
T(6,2) = T(4,2) + T(6,3) 
T(4,2) = T(2,2) + T(4,3) = T(0,2) + T(2,3) + T(1,3) + T(4,4) =
       = T(0,2) + T(2,3) + T(1,3) + T(0,4) + T(4,5) = 
       =  1     +  0     +  0     +  1     +    0 
       = 2
T(6,3) = T(3,3) + T(6,4) = T(0,3) + T(3,4) + T(2,4) + T(6,5)
       = T(0,3) + T(3,4) + T(2,4) + T(1,5) + T(6,6) = 
       = T(0,3) + T(3,4) + T(2,4) + T(1,5) + T(0,6) + T(6,7) =
       =   1    +   0    +   0    +   0    + 1      + 0 
       = 2
T(6,2) = T(4,2) + T(6,3) = 2 + 2 = 4
```

Using Dynamic Programming, it can be calculated in `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but i have some troubles understanding this ,why is T(0,k)=1 ,i can understand that T(0,0)=1 as our condition for at least k elements in a group is satisfied. but why is it 1 for T(0,1),T(0,2) etc  . Secondly can you elaborate in practical terms what does it mean when you say " think of k as the lowest possible number of balls "  .In the first part  does it mean there is a box which is currently empty and we place k balls in it?

Comment: Can you explain the two scenarios i.e  T(n-k, k)  , T(n, k + 1)  more elaborately or in practical terms ? i am unable to follow.

Comment: @Sam T(0,k)=1, because regardless of the value of `k`, if you have 0 balls left - you can place them in boxes in 1 way. Place nothing nowhere.

Comment: @Sam Regarding the two terms: you start by asking yourself, "Is there any box with exactly `k` balls?".  If so, you place `k` balls in one box, and move on - with `n-k` balls left, and set the box you just filled aside. Otherwise, you advance `k` by one, because there is no box with fewer balls than `k` (problem requirement), and also we now know there is no box with exactly `k` balls, so you can be assure all boxes have `k+1` balls or more.

Answer (score 0):

This case can be solved pretty simple:

### Number of buckets

The maximum-number of buckets `b` can be determined as follows:

```
b = roundDown(n / k)
```

Each valid distribution can use at most `b` buckets.

### Number of distributions with `x` buckets

For a given number of buckets the number of distribution can be found pretty simple:
Distribute `k` balls to each bucket. Find the number of ways to distribute the remaining balls (`r = n - k * x`) to `x` buckets:

```
total_distributions(x) = bincoefficient(x , n - k * x)
```

EDIT: this will onyl work, if order matters. Since it doesn't for the question, we can use a few tricks here:

Each distribution can be mapped to a sequence of numbers. E.g.: `d = {d1 , d2 , ... , dx}`. We can easily generate all of these sequences starting with the "first" sequence `{r , 0 , ... , 0}` and subsequently moving 1s from the left to the right. So the next sequence would look like this: `{r - 1 , 1 , ... , 0}`. If only sequences matching `d1 >= d2 >= ... >= dx` are generated, no duplicates will be generated. This constraint can easily be used to optimize this search a bit: We can only move a 1 from `da` to `db` (with `a = b - 1`), if `da - 1 >= db + 1` is given, since otherwise the constraint that the array is sorted is violated. The 1s to move are always the rightmost that can be moved. Another way to think of this would be to view `r` as a unary number and simply split that string into groups such that each group is atleast as long as it's successor.

```
 countSequences(x)
     sequence[]
     sequence[0] = r

     sequenceCount = 1

     while true
         int i = findRightmostMoveable(sequence)

         if i == -1
             return sequenceCount

         sequence[i] -= 1
         sequence[i + 1] -= 1
         sequenceCount

findRightmostMoveable(sequence)
    for i in [length(sequence) - 1 , 0)
       if sequence[i - 1] > sequence[i] + 1
           return i - 1

return -1
```

Actually `findRightmostMoveable` could be optimized a bit, if we look at the structure-transitions of the sequence (to be more precise the difference between two elements of the sequence). But to be honest I'm by far too lazy to optimize this further.

### Putting the pieces together

```
range(1 , roundDown(n / k)).map(b -> countSequences(b)).sum()
```

Comment: As far as I understand this solution, it assumes "groups" are distinct. This is not the case. (2,4) == (4,2).

Comment: @amit didn't think about that. I'll edit the answer.